# 3d navigation in rviz

Tags: ros, simulation, rviz, 3d-navigation, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in ROS. I have used stageros for 2D navigation of roomba. Now I want to simulate the 3D navigation and visualize it in rviz. Is it possible? can anyone help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9698/3d-navigation-in-rviz/) by [Ali Abdul Khaliq](https://answers.ros.org/users/414/ali-abdul-khaliq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a 3D URDF model for rviz/Gazebo of a Create (Roomba without the vacuum) see my repository [here](http://code.google.com/p/aptima-ros-pkg/).

By supplying this URDF as your robot description in the nav stack your robot will show up as this 3D model in rviz, even if you're just using a 2D simulator like Stage.

However, rviz still won't show a 3D world when using either Stage, Gazebo or even real robots in a real world because the nav stack operates on 2D costmaps built on 2D laser scans. Because of this the costmap will show up in rviz as a 2D map image with a 3D robot superimposed on it (if using a URDF for your robot)

UPDATE: If you want to try some bleeding edge 3D mapping/localization packages you could checkout the [6D-SLAM stuff](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM). You'll have to find a way of simulating a Kinect inside of Gazebo, but I'm pretty sure that has been done already (just not well documented). You'll also need something of a super-computer to run it as Gazebo+Simulated Point Clouds+6D-SLAM = a lot of processing going on.  This will give you localization and mapping, but not trajectory/path planning... You'd have to come up with your own 3D path planner.

PS If you're new to ROS, I'd stick with the 2D nav stack until things get a bit more mature.

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you want visualisation of a robot or simulation of a robot (two different things = different packages)?
Visualisation can be done in RVIZ if you create a robot model for your specific robot (don't know if there's a roomba model already available). Check the [roomba page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Roomba), it also has a navigation tutorial.
If you want simulation have a look at [Gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo) or [MORSE](http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse). They both allow you to simulate your robot in 3D and test your navigation setup, afterwards you can visualise the results in Rviz or in MORSE.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2